# Force drop a collection in MongoDB

Tags: collections, mongodb

I can't delete a collection it's telling me `false` every single time..

I do a `getCollections()` it gives me a lot of `tmp.mr.mapreduce_1299189206_1618_inc` (the ones I want to drop) I thought they were deleted during disconnection, but they're not (in my case).

Then when I do: `db["tmp.mr.mapreduce_1299188705_5595"].drop()` I always get `false`  and it's not deleted.

The logs are not really helpful:

```
Wed Mar  9 11:05:51 [conn4] CMD: drop customers.tmp.mr.mapreduce_1299188705_5595
```

Now I maxed up my namespaces and I cannot create more collections help?

BTW, I can go down, this is not production (or even in production I can put it down too).

Comment: did you try restarting your mongodb ?

Comment: Well, now I can insert and create new collections, but still they're getting listed, is this normal?

Comment: can you drop them now ? or is it still returning false ?

Comment: What is your current configuration? Is this single node, replica sets, sharded, sharded & replica sets?  What version are you running?

Comment: @DhruvPathak this is not true. each DB can span across multiple files.

Comment: I didn't, it'd take me hours to remigrate, those files include all the data not only the tmp map reduce ones.

Comment: @igorgue: can you provide some more details. What version are you running? Is this a single node, a replica set, a sharded replica set?

Comment: It's a single node, mongo version:

$ mongod --version
db version v1.6.5, pdfile version 4.5
Wed Mar  9 14:38:35 git version: 0eb017e9b2828155a67c5612183337b89e12e291

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I maxed up my namespaces and I cannot create more collections help?

By default MongoDB has 20k namespaces, so that's a lot of dead M/R collections. According to the logs, the DB is getting the request to drop the collection. So the question now is whether or not MongoDB has gotten into a bad state.

Can you take it down and re-start to ensure that all connections are closed?

Is it a lot of data? Can you take it down and run --repair?

Comment: Repair, fixed some of the indexes I couldn't delete, that saved me some space, the problem was that there was still some dead m/r collections, I just decided to delete the db and remigrate.